# Implement Search Functionality Between Two Separate React Components

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

im working with reactJs; I have implemented a two-component system where the first component features a streamlined search interface, and the second component is responsible for displaying cards. My objective is to initiate a search operation within the SearchBar component. Upon clicking the 'Search' button, I aim to seamlessly transition to the cards component, where the search query will be used to filter and display relevant cards.

I want to combine the two components while keeping them distinct

I want to combine the two components while keeping them distinct

can anyone tell me how to make it !

Answer (score 0):

maybe the flow like this.

search bar on click (hit api) > save data to reducer > return to other component using hook when data on reducer has changed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).